# How to keep the query set (filter/search) in a list after returning from add/change/delete

Tags: python, django, django-admin

A user has a change_list with the queryset is filtered by URL parameters, filter settings or a search argument, like:

localhost:8000/admin/books/book/?publisher_*id*_exact=1

On returning from a form to add or change a record, the filter is lost.

Is there any straight way to keep this state?

Answer (score 1):

Save your query string in the session. Add a 'Save and filter' button to your change view. Add a responce_change to your Admin.

To save your query string in the session. Make a new file 'BasicContextProcessor.py' in the root of your project. It contains:

```
def basics(request):
     query_string = request.META['QUERY_STRING']
     if query_string:
          request.session['query_string'] = query_string
     return
```

You probably want to extend the example above with logic to store query_string only when appropriate. Also if you have multiple change views with a 'save and filter' button, you should save the query_string for each model separate. Otherwise filters for list_view-x will be applied to list_view-y.

To process BasicContextProcessor.basics every request add it to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in Settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
   ...
   "BasicContextProcessor.basics"
)
```

Add the 'Save and filter' button to your change view. To extend change_form.html, add a file '/app_name/templates/admin/book/change_form.html'. Add a button with jQuery:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    (function($){
        $('<input type="submit" value="Save and filter" name="_viewfilterlist" />').prependTo('div.submit-row');
    })(django.jQuery);
//]]></script>
{% endblock %}
```

You can also replace the Save button to make this the default behaviour. But I like to give the user both options.

Change the response. In admin.py BookAdmin add:

```
def response_change(self, request, obj):
    if request.POST.has_key("_viewfilterlist"):
        msg = (_('The %(name)s "%(obj)s" was changed successfully.') %
               {'name': force_unicode(obj._meta.verbose_name),
                'obj': force_unicode(obj)})
        query_string = request.session['query_string']
        if query_string:
            self.message_user(request, msg)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/admin/app_name/book/?%s" % query_string)
    return super(Book, self).response_change(request, obj)
```

I didn't test these example snippets. But used this technique for other response changes. Wich worked. This should get you started. But if you find errors, I like to know. And I'll update the answer.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been a request to the Django project for a long time (the [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6903) was opened 5 years ago).

Fortunately this annoying behavior was [fixed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c86a9b63984f6692d478f6f70e3c78de4ec41814) in trunk. Expect it to be included in Django 1.6.

Comment: Yes, it is included in Django 1.6. I am going to remove that ugle work-around code.